# Can't get IP from HttpServletRequest if using "localhost" URL

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I got a problem when trying to get IP from HttpServletRequest,Please see my coding first:

```
String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
        }
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
        }
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
        }
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
        }
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
        }
        return ip;
```

My problem is if opened  application with following URL (My PC's URL is 18.111 and the server deployed on localhost) "https://192.168.18.111:8443/test/main.html",I could get right URL with above coding,But if opened with "https://localhost:8443/test/main.html",It would  return something like "0.1.0.1...." with above function,Why this function didn't work for "localhost" or does anybody know if have any better way to get IP from HttpServletRequest?

Comment: 0.1.0.1? wow, no 127.0.0.1? you have IPv6 enabled in your machine? what OS have? try with https://127.0.0.1:8443/test/main.html

Comment: My OS is ubuntu and i am not sure if i have enabled IPV6 in my machine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method's result is absolutely correct.
I assume the number that you're getting is `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`. It's valid form of loopback address. **But it's just localhost in IPv6 format**.
IPv4 address of localhost is `127.0.0.1` and IPv6 address of localhost is `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`.

The thing's that the URL `https://localhost:8443/test/main.html` matches by default both versions of IP protocol. Apparently your browser chooses to use IPv6.

For local testing try using literal address `127.0.0.1` instead of name `localhost`. Or you can make have only IPv4 address in your DNS settings.

Comment: OK,Get it,But for this"you can make have only IPv4 address in your DNS settings." How to do the setting,In browser?

Answer (score 1):

Why not trying

```
request.getRemoteAddr()
```

only? Do you really need the originating IP address (the one provided by "X-Forwarded-For")? I'm guessing that sometimes it's not useful to see some dumb LAN address instead of an addressable resource - provided by the upper method.

**Later edit:**

Have a look at this question: [Finding user ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324466/finding-user-ip-address) which seems to be fixed.

Comment: `getRemoteAddress()` doesn't provide you IP address of client, if network has intermediate nodes. This's especially true for proxies and load-balancers.

Comment: You're right, this is why I added an edit to my answer. The OP can check the correct answer from there.